# Silverlight datagrid bind nested object property

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, nested-class

I am totally  new to Sivlerlight world, so I need to know a simple thing.

how do I bind nested object as Item Source to the DataGrid.

I have a class Employee which looks Like :

```
Public class Employee
{
public long EmployeeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._employeeId;
            }
            set
            {
                this._employeeId = value;

            }
        }

public string EmployeeName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._employeeName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._employeeName = value;

            }
        }

 public tblDepartment tblDepartment
        {
            get
            {

                return this._tblDepartment;
            }
            set
            {
                this._tblDepartment = value;
            }
        }
}
```

now the class "tblDepartment" has Department name as its one of the properties, so what I want to achieve is show EmployeeId, EmployeeName and Department name in the DataGrid of Silverlight. I am using SilverLight 4.0.

Issue is I am not able to find how to bind Nested objects properties(i.e. Objects with in Objects).

can anyone help me out here,

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
{Binding Path=EmployeeObject.tblDepartment.Name}
```

Comment: It would be more natural to assume that it is an instance of an employee object being bound to, hence the "EmployeeObject" above is not necessary.  If it were then the Sumit wouldn't have know how to bind the other two properties either.

Comment: Yes. I agree. If Sumit is trying to set a columns value in datagrid he can just do {Binding Path=tblDepartment.Name}

Comment: thanks :) 

the mistake I was making was for rest of the properties(which were directly inside employee) I was using binding syntax in the following manner

<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee ID" 
                Binding="{Binding EmployeeId}" />

so on the same note if tried for department name like

 <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Department" 
                Binding="{Binding tblDepartment.DepartmentName}" /> 

I was not getting the data, I dont know why didnt this path thing struck to me :) , anyways thanks a lot